# TCPDF page rotation

Tags: php, pdf, rotation, tcpdf

I'm trying to generate a PDF file containing labels which are 202mm wide by 50mm heigh. I have managed to do this and added the required text and a barcode but my problem is that the labels print out narrow edge first so the whole page need rotating 90 degrees.

I can do this in Adobe Reader with ease by simple right clicking on the page and selecting **Rotate Clockwise** (Shift+Ctrl++) but I really need to do it in the code.

Does anyone know how to do this with TCPDF? I have tried the Rotate function but can't seem to get it working. Any examples of code would be helpful.

Comment: did you rotate the page on creation already? see http://www.tcpdf.org/examples/example_060.phps

Comment: @James interesting question because recently I was thinking about automating my portfolio in PDF and adding a digital barcode on the bottom of each project page. searching for BARCODE and PDF I landed here.  Is your problem fixed or not?

Comment: @Sam in the end I had to use another program to rotate the page. The PDF generation and barcode rendering works fine though. With having no other alternative to use, I'd probably use TCPDF again.

Comment: @James *"in the end I had to use another"*  ... I set a bounty for you hoping that more attention results to a solution. Also, I prefer "elegant solutions" over "compromis solutions" :)

Comment: @Sam ah. Cheers, I hadn't realised you had placed a bounty until I got completion notice this morning.

Comment: @James :) your welcome, have a sunny weekend, Cheers mate.

Answer (score 12):

How about setting it to landscape when building the page?

```
TCPDF::__construct($orientation = 'L',
$   unit = 'mm',
$   format = 'A4',
$   unicode = true,
$   encoding = 'UTF-8',
$   diskcache = false)
```

$orientation (string) page orientation. Possible values are (case insensitive):

- P or Portrait (default)
- L or Landscape
- '' (empty string) for automatic orientation

http://www.tcpdf.org/doc/classTCPDF.html#a5420ac8b0726a604260780d8f4185fc1

Comment: This was the firs thing that I tried but its not just the page I want to rotate. I want the text and page content to read from the bottom of the page to the top.

Answer (score 12):

What I've done with version 1.5

```
    $pdf->AddPage(); // Orientation for the first page is defined into configuration file.

    $pdf->writeHTML("Portrait 1");

    $pdf->AddPage('L');

    $pdf->writeHTML("Landscape !");

    $pdf->AddPage('P');

    $pdf->writeHTML("Portrait 2");

    $pdf->Output();
```

And this is working well.

Answer (score 5):

`Rotate` is odd. What the docs don't tell you is that you have to do a `StartTransform` first and then do a `Rotate`, then do a `StopTransform` afterwards. You can only do the `StartTransform` call after you have somehow set the X/Y position (so for example, I use `SetXY` to initially position the page, then you can call `StartTransform`). So try to do:

```
  $this->pdfinvoice->StartTransform();
  $this->pdfinvoice->Rotate(-90);
```

then add your content, then call

```
  $this->pdfinvoice->StopTransform();
```

when you're done. See how that works for you.

Comment: Using what you suggested was the closest I got to being able to rotate in TCPDF but I got all sorts of strange anomalies most likely from my complete lack of understand of how these functions work.

Comment: My guess is that entire co-ordinate system moves: you'll need to adjust all your X/Y positions accordingly, and that will require some math to get right. Unfortunately there doesn't appear to be a magical **rotate everything on this page while moving 0,0 to the top right position** method of doing it.

Comment: $page_format= array(55,55,'Rotate'=>-90); $pdf->AddPage('P', $page_format, false, false); // Also possible and you can set $pdf->SetPageUnit("mm"); in case ..

Comment: The anwer @YumYumYum has provided should actually be posted as a real answer. This actually works better than the other solutions posted.

Answer (score 1):

The `format` argument in constructor has wide range of optional parameters, including `Rotate` and support for arbitrary page `width` and `height` - example:

```
// page A4 rotated clockwise 90 deg.
$pdf = new TCPDF('L', 'pt', ['format' => 'A4', 'Rotate' => 90]); 

// page with custom size rotated clockwise 270 deg.
$pdf = new TCPDF('L', 'pt', ['format' => [$width, $height], 'Rotate' => 270]);
```

Documentation [here](https://github.com/tecnickcom/TCPDF/blob/main/tcpdf.php#L2069).

Answer (score 1):

The simplest and easy way to Landscape is:
First go to your tcpdf.config file
then go to the line

```
 * Page orientation (P=portrait, L=landscape).
 */
define ('PDF_PAGE_ORIENTATION', 'L','P');
```

Just change the "P" to 'L' save and run it.

Comment: Looks like this answer already suggests that: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6103397/5468463

Answer (score 0):

The simplest option is to set the page on Landscape mode 'L' if this is what you need.
Otherwise, if you need a page in portrait mode but with rotated objects, then you can create an XObject template and put your content there, including graphical transformations.
Check the default examples at http://www.tcpdf.org for graphical transformations and XObject templates.

Answer (score 0):

This is an old post but if anyone has this issue, I would suggest you first try out the landscape mode for the page.

This works for me:

Here is the code for setting A4 landscape:

```
$pdf->AddPage('L', 'A4');
```

Visit
https://tcpdf.org/examples/example_028/ to learn more.